# Probability of all even numbers of successes minus probability of all odd numbers of successes

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I'm reading a solution to a probability problem and it contains two equations for some $n$ and for all $k$:
$$a=\sum_{k=0;2\mid k}^n\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
$$b=\sum_{k=1;2\nmid k}^n\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
After that the solution states that $a+b=1$, which is perfectly clear since $a$ and $b$ cover all possible probabilities of all the numbers of successes of some event in $n$ trials.

But then it is said that
$$a-b=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-p)^k(1-p)^{n-k}=(1-2p)^n$$
I have no idea how they computed $a-b$ and I'd appreciate it you guys gave me any hints here.

Comment: Shouldn't $k$ start from 0 in the even case? Otherwise $a+b<1$.

Comment: Yep, my fault, should edit it.

Comment: Did it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $c_k$ for $\binom{n}k p^k(1-p)^k$.

Then
$$a=c_0+c_2+c_4+\cdots$$
(the sum should start with $k=0$) and 
$$b=c_1+c_3+c_5+\cdots.$$
So
$$a-b=c_0-c_1+c_2-c_3+c_4-c_5+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kc_k.$$
Putting the value of $c_k$ back into this gives the sum formula for $a-b$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly an extra success changes the parity of successes and a failure does not, so recursively $$a_{n+1}=(1-p)a_n+pb_n$$ $$b_{n+1}=pa_n+(1-p)b_n$$ so $$a_{n+1}-b_{n+1} = (1-2p)(a_n-b_n)$$ and induction, starting with $a_0-b_0=1-0=1$, leads to $$a_{n}-b_{n}= (1-2p)^n$$